# What's preventing my Google Workspace email transfer to Gmail from authenticating?

Tags: email, gmail, migration, google-workspace

I have enabled POP email on the source account.  However, after clicking "Import mail and contacts" I'm getting the following error message when trying to import emails to my free Gmail account from my Google Workspace account:

[image]

I know the credentials are correct and that POP is enabled and have confirmed this by adding the POP account to Thunderbird email successfully.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Read through this: `https://support.google.com/a/answer/140034?hl=en` and this `https://goodmancreatives.com/how-to-add-a-google-suite-email-to-gmail/` to see if there are any steps you are missing,

Comment: Both accounts already work and the MX records are correctly set.  I'm trying to transfer emails to a free Gmail account from a paid Google Workspace account.

Comment: Tried the official Google Workspace Migration tool https://admin.google.com/ac/dms? It might be pretty slow but perhaps easier to set up.

Comment: Neh, took another look and that doesn't let you do "to Gmail", only "from Gmail"... Do you have "Use SSL" selected (when you edit the port)?

Comment: Also, how about going a diffrent route, migrating it by downloading it and uploading it back with IMAP. Using something like [MailStore Home](https://www.mailstore.com/en/products/mailstore-home/) (or even Thunderbird https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/301-using-thunderbird-to-transfer-emails-between-servers/)

Comment: As @YisroelTech suggests, in Thunderbird, I routinely drag-and-drop IMAP email from one account to another, or from one folder to another. There is also a context menu item for *Copy to...*, as well as moving the message.

Comment: @YisroelTech, yes mate, I do have 'Use SSL' checked.  I have considered the IMAP router already but it would be a lot of work, and I have a second Workspace email I need to move afterwards also.

Comment: Why would it be a lot of work? Shouldn't be more difficult

Comment: @YisroelTech, mostly the sheer volume of emails and folders, plus limited available storage on my laptop, and not great download/upload speeds.